# Invoking a class from one project in another project?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am very new to eclipse and android developing in general and need help with the following.  I have built two android projects in Eclipse with the android SDK:

1. "ORF401 Project" - targets Android 2.2 platform
2. "Map Project" - targets Google APIs 2.2 platform

I have followed the steps as specified by the standard [Hello World Google Maps for android tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) and have gotten the Google map to display on the emulator when I run the second project.

I have a menu set up in the 1st project for which one of the options is to load the map.  However, I'm not sure how to load the map within this project since only one build target can be specified for each project, and so I cannot specify the Google Maps API as a (additional) build target.  Is there a way to call the main .java class from the second project within the first project?  I see where a reference can be made to the 2nd project under the project properties, but I'm not sure how to make use of this.  One possible solution I found on the web was to add the following code under the switch case in the first project:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, {googleMap}.class);  
startActivity(intent);
```

I presume this would require an additional googleMap.java class in the first project and also another activity, but I can't get it to work.  Can anyone make a suggestion as to how I can accomplish this?

If the code for either or both projects would help, I'll be happy to post it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main idea with projects is to have one project per application that does some thing.
I assume your application needs to do something with maps, as well as something else. There is no need to split those ideas. Keep them in one project, because they make up one single application that you develop.

First thing I would suggest - read carefully about activities and intents. Head to http://developer.android.com - everything's clearly explained.
With that all cleared up you will see the point in making some button, which, being tapped, opens a new screen with the map feature that you've developed. And then let's you go back or do something else, like open a new screen, a browser, etc.

And give up trying to call the other project from a different one :) It's not the way I think you want to do stuff.

Just to make sure I'm not misunderstood - of course you might want to have two projects. But those will most probably result in two separate applications. Luckily, applications may also interact by intents, or content providers, or a couple more. Just see how Contacts app takes you to GMail app if you want to send a mail. If that's what you want to achieve - still need to read about intents.

*edit:*
Here's the link I mentioned about in the comments:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html
It explains how to achieve the 'additional target' that you would like to have.

Comment: there are reasons to split projects up

Comment: I just added a last paragraph. Maybe that's the right way for you @Brandon?

Comment: @binnyb you are right, but one has to remember two things: the referenced project will loose it's capabilities to use it's resources in the activities; the target platform will still have to be set. There is a way to have a conditional usage of libs, more on this on android developers' team blog.

Comment: For some reason when I create a new activity and try to run it using an intent object (as described at: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/03/tutorial-how-to-start-a-new-activity/), I get an error saying the process encountered an unexpected error and was forced to close.  Not sure why.  I had coded the intent to change to the new activity within a switch case structure (not on button-click), but I can't imagine that's what is causing the error.  If I can't get it by the end of the night I may post a new message with the code included.  Thanks for the help gents

Comment: I was kinda busy sleeping, so couldn't help you. Hope you managed to read about the android manifest xml file in which you have to include the names of activities you want to be able to run.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to call a class from one project in another project, but there are bigger problems here.  The first project can run on any Android device.  The second, however, requires Google Maps APIs.  You won't be able to invoke it anyway, because it can't be installed unless you're in an environment that supports Google APIs.  There really is no benefit to doing this, unless you have additional functionality in project 1 such that it can exist without project 2.

I would suggest using the Intent method rather than trying to hack something together that allows you to access another class.  Regardless, though coupling these two together like this seems overly complicated and error prone.  I would suggest simply embedding the mapping functionality in project 1 and requiring Google APIs.  Most mainstream device support them anyway.

If you're married to the idea of having two separate projects with different build targets, I would suggest looking into using `BroadcastReceivers` with a custom intent that you broadcast from application 1.  I don't believe `startActivity` will work across application boundaries because of class loader issues, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Would you mind describing exactly what you mean by embedding the mapping functionality in project 1 and requiring Google APIs?  I have tried adding the uses-library and the internet permission into the manifest xml of project 1 and setting Google API as the build target (rather than Android 2.2) but this was giving me errors that I could not resolve.  Would I add the extends MapActivity to the the main .java class (corresponding to the activity I created for project 1), or create an entirely new class and copy the contents from project 2?

Comment: What about exporting project 2 to a .jar and adding the .jar to the library under the build path?  Would that enable me to call the class from project 2 without having to make a whole bunch of changes?  I'm working on it right now so if I figure it out I'll post again and let you know

Comment: one project could be a library project, which can be then included in the other project.  You can then launch activities that are inside the library.  they all must be declared in the manifest though.